# How to initiate logout process from External Identity provider programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm modifying some code which uses IdentityServer4, I have this scenario where the callback action method has to handle UserNotFound exception during login process, in this case I would like to logout the user from the external identity provider, I have tried a bunch of ideas to accomplish this but all of those requires a logoutId as per my understanding, now this logoutid is generated by the IdentityServer itself, so how I logout the user when it has successfully authenticated by an external identity provider but for some reason we want to log the user out and force them to try login again?

Here is the code that I was changing to make work, some of the comments marked as `todo` will give an idea of what I was trying to achieve.

The code is basically a lightly modified version from the IdentityServer doc sample and examples, please see,

- https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signout_external_providers.html
- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs

***...IdentityServer\Controllers\ExternalController.cs***

```
/// <summary>
/// Post processing of external authentication
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    try
    {
        // Read external identity from the temporary cookie
        AuthenticateResult result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
        if (!result.Succeeded)// if external authentication failed, just produce a login here URL, no need to logout from any (internal/external) provider.
        {
            if (result.Failure != null)
            {
                _logger.Error(result.Failure);
            }
            
            // todo: url for login
            // login url for should be passed via model
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Account");
        }

        // Lookup our user and external provider info
        (User user, string provider, string providerUserId, IEnumerable<Claim> claims) = await FindUserFromExternalProviderAsync(result);

        if (user == null)
        {
            // todo: aws or webex, LogoutId here
            // todo: delete local authentication cookies
            //var logoutId = await _interaction.CreateLogoutContextAsync();//it always comes as null, probably because the logout process is not initiated

            //var model = new LoggedOutViewModel
            //{
            //    LogoutId = logoutId,
            //    Reason = LogoutReasons.ACCESS_DENIED,

            //};
            // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
            //var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId, model.Reason);

            // todo: url for login
            throw new UserNotFoundException(providerUserId, null, provider);// pass LogoutId url here

            //// Redirect to the external identity provider for logout
            //string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId, reason = vm.Reason });

            //// this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
            //return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // This allows us to collect any additional claims or properties for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie
        // This is typically used to store data needed for sign out from those protocols
        var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
        var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
        ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
        ProcessLoginCallbackForSaml2p(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

        // Issue authentication cookie for user
        var identityServerUser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Subject)
        {
            DisplayName = user.Login,
            IdentityProvider = provider,
            AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(identityServerUser, localSignInProps);

        // Delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

        // Retrieve return URL
        string returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

        // Check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
        AuthorizationRequest context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.Subject, user.Login, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

        if (context != null && context.IsNativeClient())
        {
            // The client is native, so this change in how to
            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);
        }

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    catch (UserNotFoundException ex)
    {
        //_logger.Error() here
        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Account");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the IdentityServer docs, I found this article:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signout_external_providers.html

It basically says that some external providers doesnt have the logout configured, and you need to redirect to the providers and request the logout action. This is configured by AuthenticationSchemes.

And this may help you to get the logoutId, that is necessary:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html#sign-out